# handle windows message in Qt

Tags: qt

hi we can handle windows message in c# with override  WndProc

how we can do it in Qt

Comment: This should help. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/eventsandfilters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to override [QCoreApplication::winEventFilter()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qcoreapplication.html#winEventFilter) ?